# Can anyone help me to clear some questions about diodes and transistors?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

i don't understand the basic of the working of diodes, because i imagine that if we have a n-p junction and we want to pass current through from side of n region to p region, if we beat the potencial barrier, build from electronsin p side, if the currents starts to flow, but why don't electrons go to those holes that are in that moment free in the p-type semi conductors, and  thus build bigger potencial barrier? just like in the case of diffusive electrons.

Comment: Again, electrons don’t flow ‘through’ the diode - electrons come from the n-side, holes come from the p-side, and recombine in the depletion region. No electrons flow into and through the p-side.

Comment: You might want to google the avalanche effect and the zener effect, for ways that you can in fact have current flow in to the n side and out the p side.